# How to select the parent element of every nth character with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="container">
<p class="p-one">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
<p class="p-two">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
<p class="p-three">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
<p class="p-four">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
<p class="p-five">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, I would like to be able to programatically select the parent element (so in this case that would be one of the paragraphs) after a certain number of characters. So for instance, if the number was 70, I'd like to be able to count all the characters inside of #container then find the 70th character and the select the element that character belongs to which in this case would be the paragraph with class name 'p-two'. If the number was 120 it would do the same things but then instead select paragraph 'p-three'. (My goal in doing this is so I can break up a long container element that has many diverse elements inside of up into rougly equal sized blocks.)

Using .length I am able to count the characters of #container just fine, it is then selecting the parent that I run into trouble.

Comment: Will get complicated fast if there are html tags inside the paragraphs. Will that be the case? Really not clear what expected results would be either and objective is still not concise

Comment: _"So for instance, if the number was 70"_ Seventieth "text" character; excluding `html` ? , within `#container` element ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```js
var container = $("#container"); 
var stop = 70; var idx = null;

container.text(function(i, text) {
  var arr = text.split("\n").filter(Boolean);
  var n = 0;
  $.each(arr, function(key, elem) {
    n = n + elem.length;
    console.log(n, key)
    if (n > stop) {
      idx = key;
      return false;
    };
  });
});

container.find("p").eq(idx).css("background", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<p class="p-one">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
<p class="p-two">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
<p class="p-three">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
<p class="p-four">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
<p class="p-five">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than determining the text length of the `#container` element as a whole, you're going to have to do it on the `p` elements themselves. You can do this in a loop:

```
var $children = $('#container').children(),
    $selected,
    limit = 70,
    len = 0;

$children.each(function() {
    len += $(this).text().length;

    if (len > limit) {
        $selected = $(this);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here we have a `len` variable. The `each()` loop iterates through each of our `p` elements within `#container` and increments the value stored in `len` by the length of the text contained within that particular `p` element. If the `len` becomes greater than our limit, we set our `$selected` element to the currently iterating element and break out of the loop.

---

### Demo

```js
var $children = $('#container').children(),
    $selected,
    limit = 70,
    len = 0;

$children.each(function() {
  len += $(this).text().length;

  if (len > limit) {
    $selected = $(this);
    return false;
  }
});

$selected.css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p class="p-one">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
  <p class="p-two">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
  <p class="p-three">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
  <p class="p-four">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
  <p class="p-five">Some paragraph text. Some paragraph text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @charlietfl you commented when I was editing that part. Forgot to call `text()`. That's fixed now.

Comment: yeah..makes more sens.. `$(this).length` sure looked weird